# Set Image Source from app.xaml /wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, imagesource

I'm trying to get an image of my project and put it in a Style of my App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="image_campange_map" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/map.jpg"/>
</Style>
```

The problem :
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\Images\map.jpg

How could i get the local path of the Image i'm stylling ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Build Action` to "Content" and the `Output` to "Copy Always" in the Images properties.

Then create a `BitmapImage` resource instead of a style. Example:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="myKey" UriSource="Images/map.jpg"/>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Now just set your `Image` source

```
 <Image Source="{StaticResource myKey}"/>
```

Comment: Thank for this answer but could you give me an exemple please ^^ ?
I don't understand where i have to add this.

Comment: It's okay, i finally understand what was image properties ^^ 
Right Click on the Image -> Properties
But it doesn't work anyway :/

Comment: @omega478 i just remembered setting relative path in style doesn't work right. I edited my answer.Honestly though, I feel like it's easier to just set the Image Source directly. Not sure why you need a style though.

Comment: Okay @Tronald
Thx a lot for your time !

Comment: Better than Content and Copy Always would be to set the Build Action to Resource.